# What branch of mathematics improves logical thinking?

Tags: logic, soft-question, problem-solving, learning

So, that's the question. I dare to generalize it even wider: what branch of mathematics improves the general thinking ability, intilligence, the way the person thinks, and makes it more logical? I'm anticipating answers like "every branch", but I guess there are ones that do it better.

Comment: Logic.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @GitGud Some people may argue that maths is a branch of logics.

Comment: @MykeArya Either way my answer is the same.

Comment: I think a more interesting question would be "What branch of mathematics is best to introduce clear logical thinking?" That is, should elementary notions of logic and proof be introduced in a course of their own, or say at the start of an analysis, or combinatorics or elementary number theory course?

Comment: Perhaps:  discrete for broad stroke argument technique/logic, analysis for honing an eye for detail and algebra for analyzing relationships?

Comment: Why was it blocked this question? It may be interesting for some people.

Comment: @MykeArya I agree with you, but I still voted to close because of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @MykeArya: That some people may be interested in it is not a good enough reason to allow it. Look at the closure reason below.

Comment: Every branch of Mathematics (Especially pure, where you construct proofs) improves logical thinking... I don't think I can say Analysis improves logical thinking and rest don't...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There really is no "correct answer", because most highly intellectual endeavors improve one's capacity to think, and enhance logical thought.  But there are different "ways of thinking" that are all valuable, and which "ways of thinking" that a branch or subject engages and develops depends on the topic/branch.

But in general, there is no replacement for courses that emphasize critical thinking, problem solving, and introductory logic ("Elementary Logic", "Symbolic Logic") the latter sometimes offered in math departments, but also at times by Philosophy departments. Course offerings such as Discrete Mathematics cover introductory logic, elementary set theory, and a flexible array of topics which require problem solving of one form or another. For those planning to major in mathematics, there are often classes that provide a more formal introduction to proofs and higher-level mathematics, which are valuable even to those not planning to major in math.

If you are sincerely interested in improving the clarity and quality of your thinking, and becoming a versatile thinker, particularly within mathematics, I recommend each and every of the following references:

- [Polya, ***How to solve it***;](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It)
- [Velleman, ***How to Prove It***;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995)
- [Mason, Burton, Stacey, ***Thinking Mathematically***.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0273728911)

Comment: Those are all excellent books to learn from! +1